# Must use 'class' tag to refer to type '____' in this scope

Tags: c++, class, syntax-error

I have an error when trying to declare function in a .h file. The error is "Must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'Line' in this scope". Hope you can help me out with this.

```
#include "Position.h"


#ifndef PACMAN_FANTOMES_H
#define PACMAN_FANTOMES_H


class Blinky {
private:
Position m_blinky;

public:
//Constructeur
Blinky(Position);
Position PositionCourante();
};

class Pinky{
private:
Position m_pinky;

public:
//Constructeur
Blinky(Position);
Position PositionCourante(); // Here is the error, it underlines the word Position

};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, because your question fails to meet all requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], it is not possible to answer your question. You need to [edit] your question so that it meets all requirements for a [mcve]. When reading stackoverflow.com's [help], be sure to pay attention to the part that explains [ask] a question.

Comment: Unrelated: Is ghost behaviour really different enough for each ghost to need their own class?

Comment: Unrelated: You should move `#include "Position.h"` inside the [header guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: No it is not but my teacher want us to use his own code and in is version we need to create another constructor...

Answer (score 2):

One error I noticed, is that in your class `Pinky`, I noticed that you have a syntax error with the constructor.

The name of the constructor in `Pinky` is `Blinky(Position);`. This is an error because the name of the constructor must match the name of the class.

Change name of the constructor to `Pinky(Position);`

Comment: Worked! Thanks i feel stupid now :)